# What did Buster Moon say to the dancing foxes to offend them?

Tags: plot-explanation, sing

In the movie *Sing*, there is a scene where Dapper Koala tries to invite the dancing foxes to join his show. He picks up a dictionary and says something, after reading from the dictionary the foxes are offended and leave

What did he say?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [IMDB Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3470600/trivia?item=tr3403674):

> What Buster Moon said in Japanese to the five Japanese red pandas roughly translate to- "Your routine is horrible, your footwork stinks like feet". It's possible he may have wanted to say that "You are in my show, sleep well and start fresh tomorrow".

Answer (score 3):

He says "anata dashi" but correct for that is "anata tachi"
Leggo   anata tachi sugoku kusai yo 
貴方たち凄く臭いよ                                "You stink alot"
Ashi no tsune ijyo ni nitte kusai 
足のつねい所に似て臭い                       "you stink  like a foot".

Answer (score 2):

> 貴方たち凄く臭いよ足のつねい所に似て臭い (in romanji: Anata-tachi sugoku kusai yo ashi no Tsune i-sho ni nite kusai)

This roughly translates to:

> You smell so terrible, it smells like  your feet.